# Import flash.net.SecureSocket throwing error "Definition XXX could not be found"

Tags: actionscript-3, ssl, actionscript, tls1.2, flexbuilder

My requirement is to make connection using SSL and TLS from my flexbuilder AS code. I google it and found that SecureSocket() will be used to communicate with SSL and TLS from the below url,

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html

While trying to implement the same in my code, I am not able to import the namespace **SecureSocket** (`import flash.net.SecureSocket;`) and while referring it throws the error as **"Definition flash.net.SecureSocket could not be found"**

FYI - I'm using Flex Builder version 3

Comment: Documentation states that Flex Builder 3 supports Flash Player version 10 (here: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_fb.html), while SecureSocket requires Flash Player version 11 (here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html). That's probably why.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i check installed FlashPlayer version in my server(Windows server 2008 r2)? Please advice

Comment: You need Flex SDK or AIR SDK that supports Flash Player 11 or higher and only then you will be able to **compile** your code. I advise to drop the long-since-obsolete Flex Builder 3 and move on to latest Flash Builder (if you can afford it) or to free-of-charge FlashDevelop which also supports Flex and MXML.

Comment: I tried to download Flex builder latest version(Trail) but got nothing, can u please share the URL where can i download flex builder latest version. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see trials for Flex/Flash Builder either. You'd better start getting along with FlashDevelop: http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12683&sid=e9e0b57fd7df41d0175f04f1202847b4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex Builder 3 supports Flash Player version 10 [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_fb.html) and SecureSocket will be available Flash Player version 11 or Higher [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html).